# Menu does not translate on second language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a multi language Drupal 8 site. But when I change the language of the Drupal site to the second language everything changes to the selected language except the main menu.

When I change the language when I'm logged in, the main menu will be translated to the selected language.

Can someone help me to make the menu change language when a normal user select his preferenced language?

Answer (score 0):

Your menu link translations are likely not published. Check the translation details element on the translate form and make sure the published checkbox is checked.

The default behavior around that is a bit weird, especially if you create the menu links before enabling translations, there is an issue that should improve that, might already be better in 8.4

Comment: What do you mean with 'translate form'?

Comment: The place where you translated the menu link?

Comment: Everything is published but the menu is still in the original language